# How to fix NoClassDefFoundError?

Tags: java, swing, compilation

I am trying to run code from the official Oracle [website](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/RadioButtonDemoProject/src/components/RadioButtonDemo.java) to create a GUI.
I saved this code in a .java file. I ran the command:

```
javac RadioButtonDemo.java
```

No messages appeared. But when I try to run the program, I get an error message:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Java Projects>java RadioButtonDemo
Error: Could not find or load main class RadioButtonDemo
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: components/RadioButtonDemo (wrong name: RadioButtonDemo)
```

Why doesn't the code from the official Oracle website work? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix it?
I don't understand this!

**Tips from other posts don't help me.** Minus all you want.

I have JDK 16.0.1. Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Have you tried moving `RadioButtonDemo.java` to `components/RadioButtonDemo.java`, and then executing `javac components/RadioButtonDemo.java` followed by executing `java components.RadioButtonDemo` (all while keeping the working directory the same)?

Comment: It works! Can you write your solution in the answer to the question? I will vote for it. I also ask you to explain how it works. Why is it the way it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `RadioButtonDemo` class has a `package components;` statement. In typical Java, packages are represented by directories. So you have at least two options:

#### Create Directory Structure Mirroring Package Structure

1. Move `./RadioButtonDemo.java` to `./components/RadioButtonDemo.java`
2. Execute `javac ./components/RadioButtonDemo.java`
3. Execute `java components.RadioButtonDemo`

If you don't specify the output location (see below) then the compiler puts the class file(s) in the same directory as the associated source file.

#### Specify Output Location When Compiling

1. Execute `javac -d <path> ./RadioButtonDemo.java`
2. Execute `java components.RadioButtonDemo`

The `<path>` can even be the current directory (i.e. `.`). When you specify the output location the compiler creates the directory structure mirroring the package structure of the resulting class files for you.

If you specify somewhere other than the current directory for `-d` then you'll either need to navigate to that location or specify the class-path (via `-cp`, `-classpath`, or `--class-path`) when executing `java`.

---

#### Explanation for Original Problem

Now, the compiler doesn't seem to care about the directory structure—at least, it didn't care when I experimented—but the class-loading mechanism *does* seem to care. So the compiler happily compiled `RadioButtonDemo.java` despite it not being in a directory named `components`, but it (by default) puts the resulting class file(s) in the same directory as the source file.

When you execute `java RadioButtonDemo` you're telling Java to find and load a class named `RadioButtonDemo` on the class-path. The class loader, at least as currently implemented, takes that class name and resolves the expected class file resource, which is `/RadioButtonDemo.class`. It finds that class file and loads it. But the class file reports that the class' qualified name is actually `components.RadioButtonDemo`. The names don't match and so it throws an error.

Once you apply either fix the class file ends up at `./components/RadioButtonDemo.class`. Now when you execute `java components.RadioButtonDemo` you are telling Java to find and load a class named `components.RadioButtonDemo` on the class-path. The class loader takes that class name and resolves the class file resource as `/components/RadioButtonDemo.class`. It finds that class file, loads it, the names match, and everything is all good.