# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError when using package xyz; on top. Works otherwise

Tags: java

I am running a simple program *Lec01.java* in directory ...src/one. So I add **package one;** on top of the file as seen below.

Here is Lec01.java:

```
package one;

public class Lec01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Not public!");
    }
}
```

Now when I compile using **javac Lec01.java**, it compiles fine and creates a *Lab01.class* file for me in the same folder. But when I run it using **java Lab01**, it says:

*Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: one/Lec01 (wrong name: Lec01)*

But when I remove **package one;** from the start, it runs fine.

Here is the new Lec01.java, which runs fine:

```
public class Lec01 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Not public!");
    }
}
```

What I could learn from other similar questions is that **in the first case, it's not finding the generated .class file when it wants to run**. It's also related to classpath but I cannot exactly figure out how. And in the second case, it finds it as it searches in the source directory where it created the class.

But what confuses me is that the .class file gets created at the same location in both the cases, but in one case it can find it, in the second case, cannot.

Could someone please tell me what's going on?

Comment: Can you show us the commands you use to compile your classes?

Comment: Assuming your Lec01.class is in src/one directory you need to go to src directory and run from there `java one.Lec01`. You cannot run this from src/one directory.

Comment: @Flav Yes sure. While in directory ...src/one, I first use **javac Lec01.java** and then **java Lec01**

Comment: @Alex Hi, I just tried it now and it runs fine. Could you please help me find out why is it so? That's what I cannot understand. Because when I remove **package one;** from top, it runs fine like it would if it was in any other folder. Just behaves normally. I want to know what happens when I write **package one;** on top that it gives me this error. Like, does the classpath change? Or something else?

Comment: Basically, when you're in the `one` directory, that directory has become the root of the class path. So you use `java Lec01` and it expects to find the class file in the current directory, but then the class reports itself as `one.Lec01`, not `Lec01`, so the names don't match and the class fails to load. Remember, you've made the `one` directory the root of the class-path, so it's not part of the "package structure". This is fixed when you back out to `src`. This Q&A goes over a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67808023/how-to-fix-noclassdeffounderror]