# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.VideoPlayer

Tags: java, javafx

)

Not a noob, but a noob question, as Java stuff has happened so long ago in my life, I really feel old now...

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.VideoPlayer
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:314)
    at application.VideoPlayer.main(VideoPlayer.java:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: application.VideoPlayer
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:495)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:474)
    at javafx.graphics@19/javafx.application.Application.launch(Application.java:302)
    at application.VideoPlayer.main(VideoPlayer.java:8)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.execute(Main.java:434)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:205)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:132)
```

Code, VideoPlayer.java (javafx example code by some stackoverflow user)

```
package application;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class VideoPlayer extends Application {    
  public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }

  @Override public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    WebView webview = new WebView();
    webview.getEngine().load(
      "http://www.youtube.com/embed/utUPth77L_o?autoplay=1"
    );
    webview.setPrefSize(640, 390);

    stage.setScene(new Scene(webview));
    stage.show();
  }    
}
```

PATHs JAVA_HOME and PATH_TO_FX are set, bytecode generation completes without warning or error any kind: (I just added all modules I found in the fx directories to rule out something's amiss here...

```
javac --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web VideoPlayer.java
```

Now when running the bytecode using

```
java --module-path $PATH_TO_FX --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.controls,javafx.fxml,javafx.graphics,javafx.media,javafx.swing,javafx.web VideoPlayer.java
```

the error at this whining's beginning occurs.

Please, I beg you, help me out as it's for sure something incredibly stupid and I'm not only feeling old now for the java stuff so many years in my past but also incredibly stupid.

Thank you,
DaBird

PS: I tried to find whatever is missing there, regarding "application.VideoPlayer", nothing of value :-(

PPS: Linux Mint, Java SDK 19, OpenJavaFX from the project's download area, version 19

Comment: did you really append the ".java" extension on running the bytecode or is it just a copy-paste-error? The `java` command should end in `VideoPlayer`, not `VideoPlayer.java`.

Comment: Great obervation and I just shrinked a few inches.

Indeed, I used "VideoPlayer.java" instead of "VideoPlayer" without an extension when running java. It's not a c&p error, but mine.

Problem is: I did this out of tab complete as javac did not even create a bytecode-file-without-extension. There were no warnings or errors on using javac with these options, although: no bytecode file.

Now, please: shrink me again, telling me I just did two horrible mistakes on one issue :-)

Comment: PS: It created a .class file...

Comment: I have to say, you've found quite an interesting error. It says it can't find `application.VideoPlayer`, which is your own class, yet that error occurs **after** the call to your `main` method has succeeded, meaning the class has been found and loaded successfully. Seems like you've got some strange class loader issues happening.

Comment: Glad to hear I didn't failed twice in a row. Should I give it a try with some older versions? Java and JavaFX in version 18 or something like that?

Comment: No, Java/JavaFX 19 should work just fine. I would double check that you have downloaded the correct JavaFX SDK for your operating system and architecture. It may also be easier to use a build system (Maven or Gradle) and, if you're not already using one, an IDE (IntelliJ, Eclipse, NetBeans, or VS Code). Try to follow the instructions of [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) to see if you can get JavaFX up and running.

Comment: But doing `java -p <path_to_javafx> --add-modules javafx.web application.VideoPlayer` should work. Or if you change `launch(args)` to `launch(VideoPlayer.class, args)` it might work (I think that's where the weird class loader issues is coming from; may write an answer). The latter option shouldn't need a compilation step (the ability to run single-source files directly was added around Java 11). The former though should be compiled with `javac -p <path_to_javafx> -d <destination> --add-modules javafx.web VideoPlayer.java` (from what I understand of your structure from your question).

Comment: Java itself is from the Mint/Ubuntu Repositories:

`code`
java -version
openjdk version "19.0.1" 2022-10-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-Ubuntu-1ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
`code` 

FX is the link to the external download site of the "Getting Started" site you suggested above, I just checked by selecting v19/Linux/x64/SDK, selected the file, compared timestamp, name and diff to the one previously downloaded, it's identical. CPU is an i5-8400T (Don't tell its windows neighbour below the table...)1/

Comment: 2/2
I gave the two possible solutions above a go: The former one complained about a missing application.VideoPlayer while compiling, the latter one completes its run, obeys the -d flag and... still only produces a .class file, no bytecode file, unfortunately...

Comment: The `.class` file **is** the byte-code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Preface:** If you're new to JavaFX development, or need a refresher, then I recommend reading [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

---

## Building & Running Project

There are a couple things that are "wrong" with your setup.

Your `VideoPlayer` class is declared to be in the `application` package. Yet from your `javac` command, I gather your `VideoPlayer.java` file is not under a directory named `application`. In other words, your project structure should look *something like* the following:

```
<working-directory>
\---application
        VideoPlayer.java
```

Then compile the project with:

```
javac -p <path-to-javafx> --add-modules javafx.web application/VideoPlayer.java
```

<sup>**Note:** You only need to add `javafx.web` in your case, as it transitively requires `javafx.base`, `javafx.graphics`, and `javafx.controls`. Your code isn't using any of the other JavaFX modules.</sup>

And then run it with:

```
java -p <path-to-javafx> --add-modules javafx.web application.VideoPlayer
```

Notice I used the fully-qualified name of the main class `application.VideoPlayer`. This is the name of the class, not the name of the source file. You specified the source file in your question (which is part of where your error comes from).

Also, note that the project structure described above is not *strictly* necessary when compiling. It does, however, matter at run-time (at least with the default `ClassLoader` implementations). See [this other Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67808023/6395627) for more information. Though this is not where your error comes from, at least not directly.

All that said, I recommend using a build tool and/or an IDE when developing JavaFX applications. How to set these up is described in [Getting Started with JavaFX 11+](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/). But if you insist on compiling manually, then I recommend using the `-d` option to set an output directory, as that will create the correct directory structure for the class files regardless of your source file structure.

---

## Your Error

Note this section of my answer only exists to explain your error. If you follow the suggestions above and from *Getting Started with JavaFX 11+* then this error will no longer apply to you.

Your command to run your application looks like the following:

```
java -p <path-to-javafx> --add-modules javafx.web VideoPlayer.java
```

Here you're specifying the *source file* (`VideoPlayer.java`). Prior to Java 11 this would have resulted in an error (there's no class named `VideoPlayer.java` on the class-path). But you're using Java 11+, which means [JEP 330: Launch Single-File Source-Code Programs](https://openjdk.org/jeps/330) comes into play. This lets you launch a single source file without having to compile it first. It does this internally by compiling the source file into memory. This involves using a separate class loader implementation than "normal", and this is where the error comes from.

You're calling `launch(args)`. That is the `Application#launch(String...)` method, which is essentially a convenience method for `Application#launch(Class,String...)` for when the *calling class* is the application class you want to launch. In your case, the calling class is `application.VideoPlayer`.

The problem is that `Application#launch(String...)` uses the calling thread's [context class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html#getContextClassLoader()) to try and get a reference to the calling class's `Class`. By default, that seems to be the system/application class loader (see [documentation of built-in loaders](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ClassLoader.html)). But that is not the class loader that loaded the `application.VideoPlayer` class; that class was loaded by an in-memory class loader implementation. Therefore, the class cannot be found when JavaFX attempts to load it. This class loader issue is the reason why your stack trace says `application.VideoPlayer` could not be found but still show that its `main` method could be called successfully.

There are two ways to solve this if you're sticking with a single-source file execution.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Option 1:
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(VideoPlayer.class.getClassLoader());
    launch(args);

    // Option 2:
    launch(VideoPlayer.class, args);
}
```

Either approach will let the reflection code of JavaFX see your class.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your effort and your time in explaining this in depth. As I have already gone through the website mentioned above and (almost) all your hints were mentioned above, I was not too optimistic about a positive outcome, though. Inspite of grumpy-old-me I went through everything once more and...

It works!

`code`
<working-directory>
\---application
        VideoPlayer.java
`code`

was the missing piece. This said, you're right with everything, it's just that alle the other pieces were jet put in place, the "missing link" was the file system structure 1/

Comment: 2/2
I'll go with your advice and set up an IDE now, I just wanted to give this example a go for having a look at the performance penalty when using Webview for a video.

Once more: Thanks a lot!

(Many thanks to everyone else involved, too!)

Comment: *"look at the performance penalty when using Webview for a video"* -> Be careful in your analysis, the first time you use a WebView to play video, it will be quite slow because lots of things need to startup (Java VM, JavaFX runtime, WebEngine, WebView, Media stack, etc).  Subsequent executions will be much quicker.