# Trouble running an Intellij javafx file from command prompt

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, cmd

I am trying to run a javafx file from Intellij through command prompt. I have seen people use the "create command-line launchers" btn through Intellij, but for some reason that button doesn't exist for me. I know the program runs fine, but here's the error I get when I try to run it through specifically CMD:

```
C:\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib\salesGraph\src\main\java\com\example\salesgraph>java --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml salesGraph
Error: Could not find or load main class salesGraph
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/example/salesgraph/salesGraph (wrong name: salesGraph)
```

Here are all of the steps I have taken to try to run this javafx program.

1. finding the directory

```
cd C:\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib\salesGraph\src\main\java\com\example\salesgraph
```

2. Compiling the program - (first line is what I wrote)

```
javac --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml salesGraph.java

Note: salesGraph.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

Despite this note, a 'salesGraph.class' file was made in the same folder as my 'salesGraph.java' file (the file I am trying to run).

3. Final step - launching the file

```
java --module-path C:\javafx-sdk-19.0.2.1\lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml salesGraph
```

This message I sent resulted in the first error I sent up above.

I have watched many tutorials and I am struggling with this a lot, so any help would be nice.
I am on Windows 11

Thank you for any  help!!

Comment: Go to [openjfx.io](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx) and follow the [getting started documentation](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#install-javafx), section "Run HelloWorld using JavaFX SDK".

Comment: Once you have done that, I advise choosing an IDE (I recommend Idea with a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html)) and using that (if not Idea, then follow the getting started instructions for your chosen IDE at openjfx.io).  For most people, IMO, IDE development with an integrated build tool (e.g. Maven) is more productive than command-line development.

Comment: I am using command-line development as I am trying to run this JavaFX program from a java program. I assumed the only way to do it was through cmd @jewelsea

Comment: Note your error is similar to the one described in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67808023/6395627).

Comment: "_I am trying to run this JavaFX program from a java program_" -- Just to clarify, you're writing your own Java program that can _compile_ and _execute_ other Java programs?